# How to print json results when it has different form of data using php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using third party api to get city lists into my dropdown. I am getting response from third party api in this form

> "TopDestination":"14621
>
> </cityId>Amsterdam
>
> </cityName>NL
>
> </countryCode>Netherlands
>
> </countryName>AMS
>
> </cityCode>

My response is in a variable called $res and when i am trying to print like this

```
$res->TopDestination->cityId;
```

But it is not printing anything. If i am trying to print

```
$res->TopDestination;
```

It is printing results like this

14621AmsterdamNLNetherlandsAMS

What should i use to print city id ?

My response from api is like this

```
{"Error":{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":""},"Status":1,"TokenId":"59831ca1-37e8-42fd-8350-0b3699b86505","TopDestination":"14621<\/cityId>Amsterdam<\/cityName>NL<\/countryCode>Netherlands<\/countryName>AMS<\/cityCode><\/City>17249<\/cityId>Antalya<\/cityName>TR<\/countryCode>Turkey<\/countryName>ANTA<\/cityCode><\/City>9434<\/cityId>Athens<\/cityName>GR<\/countryCode>Greece<\/countryName>ATH<\/cityCode><\/City>10142<\/cityId>Bali<\/cityName>ID<\/countryCode>Indonesia<\/countryName>ABAL<\/cityCode><\/City>16974<\/cityId>Bangkok<\/cityName>TH<\/countryCode>Thailand<\/countryName>BKK<\/cityCode><\/City>3518<\/cityId>Barcelona<\/cityName>ES<\/countryCode>Spain<\/countryName>BCN<\/cityCode><\/City>23131<\/cityId>Basel<\/cityName>CH<\/countryCode>Switzerland<\/countryName>BSL<\/cityCode><\/City>23884<\/cityId>Beijing<\/cityName>CN<\/countryCode>China<\/countryName>PEK<\/cityCode><\/City>13551<\/cityId>Beirut<\/cityName>LB<\/countryCode>Lebanon<\/countryName>BEY<\/cityCode><\/City>1996<\/cityId>Berlin<\/cityName>DE<\/countryCode>Germany<\/countryName>BER<\/cityCode><\/City>24602<\/cityId>Brussels<\/cityName>BE<\/countryCode>Belgium<\/countryName>BRU<\/cityCode><\/City>10085<\/cityId>Budapest<\/cityName>HU<\/countryCode>Hungary<\/countryName>BUD<\/cityCode><\/City>2418<\/cityId>Cairo<\/cityName>EG<\/countryCode>Egypt<\/countryName>CAI<\/cityCode><\/City>32443<\/cityId>Cape Town<\/cityName>ZA<\/countryCode>South Africa<\/countryName>CPT<\/cityCode><\/City>20491<\/cityId>Chicago<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>CHI<\/cityCode><\/City>125<\/cityId>Cologne<\/cityName>DE<\/countryCode>Germany<\/countryName>CGN<\/cityCode><\/City>13616<\/cityId>Colombo<\/cityName>LK<\/countryCode>Sri Lanka<\/countryName>CMB<\/cityCode><\/City>2142<\/cityId>Copenhagen<\/cityName>DK<\/countryCode>Denmark<\/countryName>CPH<\/cityCode><\/City>25921<\/cityId>Dubai<\/cityName>AE<\/countryCode>United Arab Emirates<\/countryName>DXB<\/cityCode><\/City>32515<\/cityId>Durban<\/cityName>ZA<\/countryCode>South Africa<\/countryName>DUR<\/cityCode><\/City>27352<\/cityId>Dusseldorf<\/cityName>DE<\/countryCode>Germany<\/countryName>DUS<\/cityCode><\/City>8030<\/cityId>Edinburgh<\/cityName>GB<\/countryCode>United Kingdom<\/countryName>EDI<\/cityCode><\/City>11213<\/cityId>Florence<\/cityName>IT<\/countryCode>Italy<\/countryName>FLR<\/cityCode><\/City>22753<\/cityId>Frankfurt<\/cityName>DE<\/countryCode>Germany<\/countryName>FRA<\/cityCode><\/City>23435<\/cityId>Geneva<\/cityName>CH<\/countryCode>Switzerland<\/countryName>GVA<\/cityCode><\/City>26698<\/cityId>Gold Coast<\/cityName>AU<\/countryCode>Australia<\/countryName>OOL<\/cityCode><\/City>23960<\/cityId>Guangzhou<\/cityName>CN<\/countryCode>China<\/countryName>CAN<\/cityCode><\/City>379<\/cityId>Hamburg<\/cityName>DE<\/countryCode>Germany<\/countryName>HAM<\/cityCode><\/City>9926<\/cityId>Hong Kong<\/cityName>HK<\/countryCode>Hong Kong<\/countryName>HKG<\/cityCode><\/City>26996<\/cityId>Innsbruck<\/cityName>AT<\/countryCode>Austria<\/countryName>INN<\/cityCode><\/City>23037<\/cityId>Interlaken<\/cityName>CH<\/countryCode>Switzerland<\/countryName>INTE<\/cityCode><\/City>17306<\/cityId>Istanbul<\/cityName>TR<\/countryCode>Turkey<\/countryName>IST<\/cityCode><\/City>32569<\/cityId>Johannesburg<\/cityName>ZA<\/countryCode>South Africa<\/countryName>JNB<\/cityCode><\/City>15054<\/cityId>Kathmandu<\/cityName>NP<\/countryCode>Nepal<\/countryName>KTM<\/cityCode><\/City>14386<\/cityId>Kuala Lumpur<\/cityName>MY<\/countryCode>Malaysia<\/countryName>KUL<\/cityCode><\/City>35827<\/cityId>Kuwait<\/cityName>KW<\/countryCode>Kuwait<\/countryName>KWI<\/cityCode><\/City>14285<\/cityId>Langkawi<\/cityName>MY<\/countryCode>Malaysia<\/countryName>LANK<\/cityCode><\/City>32827<\/cityId>Las Vegas<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>LAS<\/cityCode><\/City>9245<\/cityId>London<\/cityName>GB<\/countryCode>United Kingdom<\/countryName>LON<\/cityCode><\/City>34549<\/cityId>London<\/cityName>CA<\/countryCode>Canada<\/countryName>YXU<\/cityCode><\/City>18631<\/cityId>Los Angeles<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>LAX<\/cityCode><\/City>23273<\/cityId>Lucerne<\/cityName>CH<\/countryCode>Switzerland<\/countryName>LUCE<\/cityCode><\/City>13674<\/cityId>Macau<\/cityName>MO<\/countryCode>Macau<\/countryName>MFM<\/cityCode><\/City>3000<\/cityId>Madrid<\/cityName>ES<\/countryCode>Spain<\/countryName>MAD<\/cityCode><\/City>14254<\/cityId>Mauritius<\/cityName>MU<\/countryCode>Mauritius<\/countryName>MRUW<\/cityCode><\/City>26916<\/cityId>Melbourne<\/cityName>AU<\/countryCode>Australia<\/countryName>MEL<\/cityCode><\/City>11297<\/cityId>Milan<\/cityName>IT<\/countryCode>Italy<\/countryName>MIL<\/cityCode><\/City>266<\/cityId>Munich<\/cityName>DE<\/countryCode>Germany<\/countryName>MUC<\/cityCode><\/City>13443<\/cityId>Nairobi<\/cityName>KE<\/countryCode>Kenya<\/countryName>NBO<\/cityCode><\/City>28985<\/cityId>New York<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>NYC<\/cityCode><\/City>4419<\/cityId>Nice<\/cityName>FR<\/countryCode>France<\/countryName>NCE<\/cityCode><\/City>19533<\/cityId>Orlando<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>ORL<\/cityCode><\/City>4775<\/cityId>Paris<\/cityName>FR<\/countryCode>France<\/countryName>PAR<\/cityCode><\/City>36773<\/cityId>Pattaya Beach<\/cityName>TH<\/countryCode>Thailand<\/countryName>PATT<\/cityCode><\/City>14321<\/cityId>Penang<\/cityName>MY<\/countryCode>Malaysia<\/countryName>PEN<\/cityCode><\/City>17093<\/cityId>Phuket<\/cityName>TH<\/countryCode>Thailand<\/countryName>PHUW<\/cityCode><\/City>24332<\/cityId>Prague<\/cityName>CZ<\/countryCode>Czech Republic<\/countryName>PRG<\/cityCode><\/City>12771<\/cityId>Rome<\/cityName>IT<\/countryCode>Italy<\/countryName>ROM<\/cityCode><\/City>27022<\/cityId>Salzburg<\/cityName>AT<\/countryCode>Austria<\/countryName>SZG<\/cityCode><\/City>18857<\/cityId>San Diego<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>SAN<\/cityCode><\/City>18861<\/cityId>San Francisco<\/cityName>US<\/countryCode>United States<\/countryName>SFO<\/cityCode><\/City>23909<\/cityId>Shanghai<\/cityName>CN<\/countryCode>China<\/countryName>SHA<\/cityCode><\/City>23976<\/cityId>Shenzhen<\/cityName>CN<\/countryCode>China<\/countryName>SHEN<\/cityCode><\/City>16532<\/cityId>Singapore<\/cityName>SG<\/countryCode>Singapore<\/countryName>SIN<\/cityCode><\/City>34326<\/cityId>Sydney<\/cityName>AU<\/countryCode>Australia<\/countryName>SYD<\/cityCode><\/City>13420<\/cityId>Tokyo<\/cityName>JP<\/countryCode>Japan<\/countryName>TYO<\/cityCode><\/City>34661<\/cityId>Toronto<\/cityName>CA<\/countryCode>Canada<\/countryName>YTO<\/cityCode><\/City>25561<\/cityId>Vancouver<\/cityName>CA<\/countryCode>Canada<\/countryName>YVR<\/cityCode><\/City>11501<\/cityId>Venice<\/cityName>IT<\/countryCode>Italy<\/countryName>VCE<\/cityCode><\/City>27059<\/cityId>Vienna<\/cityName>AT<\/countryCode>Austria<\/countryName>VIE<\/cityCode><\/City>23418<\/cityId>Zermatt<\/cityName>CH<\/countryCode>Switzerland<\/countryName>ZERM<\/cityCode><\/City>23424<\/cityId>Zurich<\/cityName>CH<\/countryCode>Switzerland<\/countryName>ZRH<\/cityCode><\/City><\/Cities>"}
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete response from the 3rd party API?

Comment: Please add the relevant portion of the JSON structure you have to the question.

Comment: I have added, please have a look

Comment: Added an answer. The problem is that the Json that comes from the API is an invalid XML (doesn't have all the tags) so you cannot parse it. You have to workaround this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the JSON response from the API. Your array $res['TopDestination'] contains just a string, thus you cannnot access "cityId". You have to PROCESS the $res['TopDestination'].

Based on your JSON this should work (it's tested!):

```
<?php
// $json = result from API (a valid JSON string!)
$res=json_decode($json, true);

// get TopDestination string into an array
$data=explode("</City>", $res["TopDestination"]);
array_pop($data);
// create a new Database of cities
$cities=array();

foreach ($data as $d) {
  $tmp=explode("</cityId>",$d);
  $city_id=$tmp[0];
  $tmp=explode("</cityName>", $tmp[1]);
  $city_name=$tmp[0];
  $tmp=explode("</countryCode>", $tmp[1]);
  $country_code=$tmp[0];
  $tmp=explode("</countryName>", $tmp[1]);
  $country_name=$tmp[0];
  $city_code=$tmp[1];

  // add the city info in the database
  $cities[]=array(
    "cityId" => $city_id,
    "cityName" => $city_name,
    "cityCode" => $city_code,
    "countryCode" => $country_code,
    "countryName" => $country_name,
  );
}

// print the database array to check it
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($cities);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

The result is... :)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [cityId] => 14621
        [cityName] => Amsterdam
        [cityCode] => AMS
        [countryCode] => NL
        [countryName] => Netherlands
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cityId] => 17249
        [cityName] => Antalya
        [cityCode] => ANTA
        [countryCode] => TR
        [countryName] => Turkey
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [cityId] => 9434
        [cityName] => Athens
        [cityCode] => ATH
        [countryCode] => GR
        [countryName] => Greece
    )

[3] => Array
    (
...
```

Comment: It is showing this error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in"

Comment: You have to be careful what you put in the json_decode function. In my code I put the JSON string in $json (it has to be a string!). I made an edit to the post to explain what $json and what $res is in my code.

Comment: Yes i have also put correct json string in json_decode which i got from curl response

Comment: 1. Show me the complete error text.  2. Show me the line where you use json_decode - what is the first parameter. (I know it works because I just copy-paste your json code into $json and tested the script).

Comment: This is what i did using your code http://codepad.org/wqWzcpRW have a look

Comment: :) you have a problem here line 19: change this: $frhw = json_decode($server_output1); INTO THIS: $frhw = json_decode($server_output1, TRUE); // (see my code)

Comment: You have to use the second parameter "TRUE" in the json_decode function to get an associative array. Check the manual. http://php.net/manual/ro/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I did that but now it is showing only blank array like this 

Array
(
)

Comment: Hm. 1. What is $str in your code (that part is missing). 2. do a var_dump on $server_output1. What is it? (Are you getting a valid response there?). (Where are the POST fields that you send by curl?)

Comment: Got it, you are right, your solution saved my time, thanks